# Create two sets of lists, each list has a header and then a list of items

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering what would be the best method two 4 column lists of html links in .net?

List will be based on data from a table - selecting a category and then each subcategory in that category. Already have the html markup for this in place.

I can do this pretty simply enough in code just building up a string. But i was wondering if there was a better way to handle it. Would one of the data controls work for this? I prefer using a control when possible as opposed to just building a raw html string. Plus i just want to know what the best way is to handle something like this.

If it matters, the underlying data looks something like this:
Category table and a product table. Using the product table so i only select categories that have items in it. There's another table, categoryrelationship, which defines the parent and child relationship i.e. categories and subcategories. Product table has a catgory and subcategory column which links to the category table.

The html basically looks like this:

```
<div class="out-wrapper">
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
</div>

<div class="out-wrapper">
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<h3> categoryName /<h3>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
<a href=""> subcat name</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like this would be a good fit for the html table tag: you have columns, data originally comes from a database. It's a valid semantic use for the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would prefer to use controls, you can nest a `Repeater` inside a `Listview` for example:

**HTML**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource"
            ondatabound="ListView1_DataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <h3><%# Eval("categoryName") %></h3>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("categoryID") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater ID="NestedRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <a href=''><%# Eval("subcat") %></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</asp:ListView>
```

**CODEBEHIND**

```
protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetCategories();
}

private void GetCategories()
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    using (db)
    {

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
        {
            Repeater rpt = (Repeater)item.FindControl("NestedRepeater");
            HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HdnId");

            var nest = from i in db.categories
                       where i.catid == Convert.ToInt32(hdn.Value)
                       select new
                       {
                           i.subcat_name
                       };

            rpt.DataSource = nest;
            rpt.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to store the ID in a hidden field then use that to retrieve the sub categories.

This is purely just an example and a possible way to use nested controls.

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but I'm not familiar with working with LINQ. I get the rest of what you are saying. Although without using LINQ i'm not sure how to do it without making multiple calls to the database - once for each category.

One other thing i just noticed - i'd need to have two listview/repeater combos for this to work since i want two sets of 4 lists, or am I missing something in your code that allows that? Thanks.

Comment: nevermind - read up on the groupitem property of the listview. Still have to make multiple (sort of) database calls but this is less of an issue for me since the data i actually want is cached anyhow. Accepted your answer - thank you